# mongodb pipeline aggregation pipeline replacing values

Tags: mongodb

If I have documents and I'm aggregating and I want to sub a field like:

```
{data: {'date_created': '2011-01-01', 'title': 'abc'}, 'owner': 'Jim'}
{data: {'date_created': '2011-05-01', 'title': 'def'}, 'owner': 'Bob'}
{data: {'date_created': '2011-03-01', 'title': 'ghi'}, 'owner': 'Jim'}
{data: {'date_created': '2011-03-01', 'title': ''}, 'owner': 'Sam'}
```

and I want to aggregate so that I only take titles created before a certain date or return an empty list, how would I structure the aggregate pipeline?

So desired output would be:

```
{owner: "Jim", titles: ["abc", "def"],
 owner: "Bob", titles: [],
 owner: "Sam", titles: []}
```

I have an aggregate pipeline that goes something like:

```
lookup => unwind => 
        {'$match':
            {'$or': [{'data.date_created': {'$lte': requested_date}}, {'data.title': {'$exists': False}}]}}}
```

but I can't figure out how to cast the data where the date created is after the required time to be blank so it'll be grouped with the blank titles.

Comment: Although non standard, you can simplify it if you like by using dummy field (non existent field) which `$push` will absorb and will not add anything.  `{"$group":{
     _id:"$owner",titles:{
         $push: { $cond:[
         { $lte: [ "$data.date_created", requested_date]},"$data.title","$nonexist"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps. You can do conditional push on the basis of date and then filter out the blank items from the titles array.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {"$group":{
     _id:"$owner",titles:{
         $push: { $cond:[
         { $lte: [ "$data.date_created", "2011-03-01" ]},"$data.title",""
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
  $project: {
       _id:0,
       owner : "$_id",
       titles: {
        $filter: {
           input: "$titles",
           as: "titles",
           cond: { $ne: [ "$$titles", "" ] }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Result :

```
{ "titles" : [ ], "owner" : "Bob" }
{ "titles" : [ "abc", "ghi" ], "owner" : "Jim" }
{ "titles" : [ ], "owner" : "Sam" }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't strictly require the empty arrays when there are no items matching your criteria, that would make it much simpler. If that were the case you could simply do a `$match` and a `$group` with either `$push` or `$addToSet`.

For example:

```
db.foo.aggregate([
    { $match : {'data.date_created': {'$lte': "2011-03-01"}}},
    { $group: {
       _id: "$owner",
       titles : {$push : "$data.title"}
    }}
])
```

Results:

```
{ "_id" : "Sam", "titles" : [ "" ] }
{ "_id" : "Jim", "titles" : [ "abc", "ghi" ] }
```

Another option would be to do your `$group / $push` first, then filter the array elements using [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) (requires MongoDB 3.2+).

For example:

```
db.foo.aggregate([
    { $group: {
       _id: "$owner",
       data : {$push : "$data"}
    }},
    {
      $project: {
         titles: {
            $filter: {
               input: "$data",
               as: "item",
               cond: { $lte: [ "$$item.date_created", "2011-03-01" ] }
            }
         }
    }}
])
```

Results:

```
{ "_id" : "Sam", "titles" : [ { "date_created" : "2011-03-01", "title" : "" } ] }
{ "_id" : "Bob", "titles" : [ ] }
{ "_id" : "Jim", "titles" : [ { "date_created" : "2011-01-01", "title" : "abc" }, { "date_created" : "2011-03-01", "title" : "ghi" } ] }
```